# Three.js set opacity for PlaneGeometry wireframe

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, opacity, wireframe

I'm new to Three.js, and trying to make an audio-driven terrain with PlaneGeometry  and WebAudioApi.

I have a PlaneGeometry in wireframe mode, and I need to keep it visually as a wireframe. But wireframe lines should have opacity, and they can't have one.
My animation translates mesh vertices on Y axis, so as far as i know THREE-helpers is not an option since they can't be animated, right?

So is there a way to map Lines to a Plane faces and make the lines connected with all neighbor vertices, so it will act like a mesh and i'll be able to set opacity to Lines? Or maybe there is a better approach?

Comment: `var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "red",  wireframe: true,  transparent: true,  opacity: 0.25});` this sets transparency to the lines of a wireframed mesh (plane)

Comment: @prisoner849 wow, that was one kind of a miss from my side. It was first thing that i've tried but somehow it didn't worked then, and now everything works great. Thank you!